# When does Razor view engine convert IActionResult to HTML?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razorengine

We know that Razor view engine converts `ViewResult`(`IActionResult`) to HTML response which can be sent to users. Below is a picture on Filter pipeline:
[image]

My question is, at which stage the Razor view engine will kick in and does the `IActionResult` to HTML transformation, right after Endpoint finishes execution or right after Resource filters finishes execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, what we definitely know is that ExecuteResult method of the ViewResult class calls into the view engine.

```
public void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ViewName))
     ViewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
  var viewEngineResult = (ViewEngineResult) null;
  if (View == null)
  {
      viewEngineResult = this.FindView(context);
      View = viewEngineResult.View;
  }
  var output = context.HttpContext.Response.Output;
  View.Render(new ViewContext(context, this.View, this.ViewData, this.TempData, output), output);
  if (viewEngineResult == null)
     return;
  viewEngineResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(context, this.View);
}
```

So from the code above I assume that the HTML rendering part happens inside this method.
Also we know that IResourceFilter has two methods (the async version IAsyncResultFilter):

```
void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
```

The first method OnResourceExecuting executes right before our api endpoint has been called.

```
[SimpleResourceFilter]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

And we can claim that ExecuteResult will be invoked after OnResourceExecuting.
To verify what method will be invoked first OnResourceExecuted() or ExecuteResult() you can place debug breakpoints it both of them. The invocation order of this two methods should give you an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I can't put a debug breakpoint in `ExecuteResult()` since it is external assembly only metadata is available. Could you give me more hints sorry I'm new to C# programming

Comment: Yes because it is external .dll I know two approaches to it. First of all, In case you have a resharper installed, you can find out how to debug external source code via resharper.
Second approach, does not require any additional tools to be installed. You can pull the mvc .net core mvc source code from github, build it in debug mode, and change the .dll you are currently using in your project to the .dll you have built. Here is an example [link](https://medium.com/@joni2nja/how-to-debug-and-patch-asp-net-mvc-core-source-code-9084bec8d138)

Comment: Because the stackoverflow has limitation of the comments length, I strongly suggest you to search in the internet something like - how to debug asp.net core source code. Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: And in case you will take second solution for the debugging, do not forget to make a backup of your currently using dll's!